# Monterey - create new user & group with IDs 1000

Tags: macos, user-account, monterey

I was trying to create a new user and a new group with the IDs of 1000 (requirement) but I ended up not being able to log in to the account in a regular way from the Login screen, however login from the terminal worked just fine. All I got on the Login screen was an endless spinning wheel and the user didn't show up with the other users. Any ideas?

I created a new group & user from Users&Groups in Preferences and then changed the User's GroupID to 1000 manually in the advanced settings. Trying with `dscl` in terminal yielded no better results.

Comment: Did you also change ownership in /Users etc?

Comment: @nohillside Yep, changed the permissions to read&write for the `/Users/myuser` for the myuser but also for the newly created group that user was in.

Answer (score 3):

I think the login window only allows logins with UID in range 500-999.

The lower number is well documented.

The upper number is from memory although secondary references include https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/how-to-hide-user-accounts-from-the-log-in-window-in-os-x/ (This can be read as only the user 1000 but 1001 is OK)
and a comment to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/118990/237

This [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/v9x5y/comment/c53jyao/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) suggests UID >= 1000 are for users managed by network directory services etc

> UIDs of 1000 and greater are generally reserved for Network/Mobile accounts. Like Open Directory, Active Directory and Open LDAP, etc.

Comment: The fact that the user doesn't show up on the Login screen but I have to manually type the username & password doesn't bother me that much honestly, I was more wondering why I couldn't log in at all in the GUI but in the terminal yes.